# Rails 4.1 ActionController::UnknownFormat in index method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, rails-activerecord, actioncontroller

I am a noob. After an exhaustive search of other questions, I was unable to find similar posts with clear and correct answers.
First, let me explain that my app has nested associations as follows:

- User has one customer
- Customer has many accounts
- User has many accounts *through* customer

So far, I've created a user with Devise, and then manually assigned her to a customer object in the console. Also created a corresponding Account in the console. (Haven't worked out the form yet for the nested creation).

All I want to do right now is bring the user, once logged in, to a "landing" page which shows her a listing of her accounts. It sounds pretty simple, but I get the following error:

### ActionController::UnknownFormat in AccountsController#index

The code referenced by the error...

```
    @accounts = @user.accounts

          respond_to do |format|
          format.html # index.html.erb
          format.json { render json: @account }
    end
```

**Here is the whole method in the Accounts Controller...**

```
    def index
      @user = current_user
      @accounts = @user.accounts

        respond_to do |format|
          format.html # index.html.erb
          format.json { render json: @account }
        end
    end
```

I don't understand what's causing the error. Here is the view code for the Accounts index...

```
    <h1>Listing accounts</h1>

    <table id="indexTable" class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th colspan="5"></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
         <% if Account.exists? %>
          <% for account in @accounts do %>
          <tr>
            <td><%= account.id %></td>
            <td><%=  %></td>

            <td><%= link_to 'Show', account %></td>
            <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_account_path(account) %></td>
            <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', account, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
          </tr>
          <% end %>
        <% else %>
          <div class="jumbotron" style="text-align: center; border: 1px solid #DDD; border-radius: 8px;">
          <h1>No accounts to display</h1>
          </div>
        <% end %>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <br>

    <%= link_to 'New Account', new_account_path %>
```

I admit, the view itself may have its own issues. But it's not even getting to the view. The error points to the controller, but could it be a problem with *routing*? This is what **routes.rb** looks like...

```
    Rails.application.routes.draw do
      devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }

      devise_scope :user do
        post "/accounts/adminview" => "devise/sessions#new"
      end
    ...
    root 'home#index'
    ...
    resources :accounts do
        member do
          get :adminview
        end
      end

      resources :account_types, :accounts, :administrators, :customers, :transaction_types, :transactions, :users
    ...
    end
```

It seems like there should be a simple solution for this, but I am a **noob**. Can anyone help me understand what to do? How do I get rid of this error and take my user to a listing of her accounts?

Thank you

I'm using Rails 4.1.8

### UPDATE

As requested, here is the whole stack trace...

```
    actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:440:in `retrieve_collector_from_mimes'
    actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:256:in `respond_to'
    app/controllers/accounts_controller.rb:11:in `index'
    actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
    actionpack (4.1.8) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
    actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
    actionpack (4.1.8) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
    activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
    activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
    activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
    activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
    activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
    activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `call'
    activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
    activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `call'
    activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
    activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `call'
    activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
    activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
    activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
    activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
    activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
    activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
    activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
    activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `call'
    activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
    actionpack (4.1.8) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
    actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
    actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
    activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
    activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
    activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
    actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
    actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
    activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
    actionpack (4.1.8) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
    actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
    actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
    actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
    actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:232:in `block in action'
    actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `call'
    actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `dispatch'
    actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `call'
    actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:73:in `block in call'
    actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
    actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
    actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:678:in `call'
    warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
    warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
    warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
    rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
    rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
    rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
    actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
    ctionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:254:in `call'
    rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
    rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
    actionpack (4.1.8)         lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
    activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
    activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in `call'
    activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/migration.rb:380:in `call'
    actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
    activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
    actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
    actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
    actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
    actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
    actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
    railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
    railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
    activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
    activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
    activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
    railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
    actionpack (4.1.8)         lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
    rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
    rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
    activesupport (4.1.8)         lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
    rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
    actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:84:in `call'
    rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
    railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
    railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
    rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
    puma (2.11.1) lib/puma/server.rb:507:in `handle_request'
    puma (2.11.1) lib/puma/server.rb:375:in `process_client'
    puma (2.11.1) lib/puma/server.rb:262:in `block in run'
    puma (2.11.1) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:104:in `call'
    puma (2.11.1) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:104:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

### UPDATE

As requested, the full Accounts controller...

```
    class AccountsController < ApplicationController
      before_filter :authenticate_user!
      before_action :set_account, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

      # GET /accounts
      # GET /accounts.json
      def index
        @user = current_user
        @accounts = @user.accounts

          respond_to do |format|
          format.html # index.html.erb
          format.json { render json: @accounts }
        end
      end

      def adminview
        @accounts = Account.all

        respond_to do |format|
          format.html # adminview.html.erb
          format.json { render json: @accounts }
        end
      end

      # GET /accounts/1
      # GET /accounts/1.json
      def show
      end

      # GET /accounts/new
      def new
        @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
        @customer = @user.customer.build
        @account = @customer.accounts.build

        respond_to do |format|
          format.html # new.html.erb
          format.json { render json: @account }
        end
      end

      # GET /accounts/1/edit
      def edit
      end

      # POST /accounts
      # POST /accounts.json
      def create
        @account = Account.new(account_params)

        respond_to do |format|
          if @account.save
            format.html { redirect_to @account, notice: 'Account was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @account }
          else
            format.html { render :new }
            format.json { render json: @account.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end

      # PATCH/PUT /accounts/1
      # PATCH/PUT /accounts/1.json
      def update
        respond_to do |format|
          if @account.update(account_params)
            format.html { redirect_to @account, notice: 'Account was successfully updated.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @account }
          else
            format.html { render :edit }
            format.json { render json: @account.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end

      # DELETE /accounts/1
      # DELETE /accounts/1.json
      def destroy
        @account.destroy
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { redirect_to accounts_url, notice: 'Account was successfully destroyed.' }
          format.json { head :no_content }
        end
      end

      private
        # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
        def set_account
          @account = Account.find(params[:id])
        end

        # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
        def account_params
          params[:account]
        end
    end
```

### UPDATE

As requested, the logs just before the error (starting at sign in)...

```
    Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-07 12:28:50 -0500
    Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
    Rendered devise/shared/_links.html.erb (0.5ms)
    Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (3.5ms)
    Rendered application/_navigation.html.erb (0.5ms)
    Completed 200 OK in 166ms (Views: 163.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


    Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-07 12:28:54 -0500
    Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
    Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"7Eoj56l0rRcheddj2tSE9sSm+5wXi7/bxVVFsPga+XM=", "user"=>{"login"=>"charlie", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Log in"}
      User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users`  WHERE (lower(username) = 'charlie' OR lower(email) = 'charlie')  ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
    (0.2ms)  BEGIN
    SQL (0.5ms)  UPDATE `users` SET `current_sign_in_at` = '2015-03-07 17:28:54', `last_sign_in_at` = '2015-03-07 17:27:42', `sign_in_count` = 17 WHERE `users`.`id` = x'ac045b738f9c446f9cc2d86b01cea3b7'
    (94.7ms)  COMMIT
    Redirected to http://localhost:3000/accounts.ac045b73-8f9c-446f-9cc2-d86b01cea3b7
    Completed 302 Found in 187ms (ActiveRecord: 96.2ms)


    Started GET "/accounts.ac045b73-8f9c-446f-9cc2-d86b01cea3b7" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-07 12:28:54 -0500
    Processing by AccountsController#index as 
      User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users`  WHERE `users`.`id` = x'ac045b738f9c446f9cc2d86b01cea3b7'  ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
    Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 6ms

    ActionController::UnknownFormat (ActionController::UnknownFormat):
      app/controllers/accounts_controller.rb:11:in `index'


    Rendered /home/barnabas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (0.9ms)
    Rendered /home/barnabas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (1.4ms)
    Rendered /home/barnabas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.1ms)
    Rendered /home/barnabas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (14.3ms)
```

Comment: Where is error with backtrace?

Comment: Try to remove duplicates of :accounts from routes.rb in last `resources` of your example here.

Comment: Can you post logs from just before the error?

Comment: @maxd Tried that and restarted server. Still produces same error.

Comment: This error mean that Rails can't determine type of your request and select appropriate response type. May be problem related to your browser? Try to reproduce problem in private mode or other browser.

Comment: @basia Updated post to show session logs leading to the error. Thanks

Comment: @maxd Thanks. Tried originally in Chrome. Per your suggestion, I tried in FireFox but still get the exact same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `/accounts.ac045b73-8f9c-446f-9cc2-d86b01cea3b7` your app is taking as format `ac045b73-8f9c-446f-9cc2-d86b01cea3b7` but your controller only knows how to handle `html` and `json`.

You should verify why `/users/sign_in` is redirecting to that weird link

Comment: "ac045b73-8f9c-446f-9cc2-d86b01cea3b7" is actually the (binary uuid) user_id of the user ("Charlie") that has just logged in. I'm using Devise and in my Application Controller, I've defined the **after_sign_in_path** as `accounts_path(current_user)`. Is this incorrect? Basically trying to send it to the current user's accounts index.

Comment: Maybe try changing after_sign_in_path to `accounts_path(current_user, format: :html)`

Comment: That did it!! Works perfectly now :) Thank you so much, Aguardientico!!

Answer (score 0):

The only error I can see is that in your controller, this:

```
format.json { render json: @account }
```

should be

```
format.json { render json: @accounts }
```

Notice the extra 's' on @accounts. But that may not be all of it. If it is, great! If not can yo post your full Accounts controller and stack trace so we can work through this?

Comment: Thanks for answering. Unfortunately it didn't change. Now I get the same error, but with `format.json { render json: @accounts }` in the reference